# How can I make a discord bot that does something like this?

Tags: javascript, c#, discord, discord.js, discord.net

I want to make a discord bot that when a discord user (called DiscordName # 123) sends a command to the bot by private (Command example! Pass) if the name of that discord user is in a column of my user table from mysql the bot will return a message with columns from that table and if the user's name is not in that column the bot will reply a message.

Comment: please leave sample codes

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rows.length => 0){
return message.channel.send("no data found")
}
```

Not sure if this is what your looking for but put it under throw err; if it is what you need